# Recursively get all files in a hard disk

Tags: c, windows

Please I am finding it hard to recursively get all files in a directory. My code works fine, just that it only get files in current directory. Please anyone should help me view my code to check what i have done wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int list2() {
    TCHAR currentdir[MAX_PATH];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findDat2;
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, currentdir);
    strcat_s(currentdir, strlen(currentdir)+strlen("\\*")+1, "\\*");
    HANDLE hFind2 = FindFirstFile(currentdir, &findDat2);
    if (hFind2 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("INVALID HANDLE VALUE");
    }
    else {
        INT dot1 = strncmp(".", findDat2.cFileName, strlen("."));
        INT dot2 = strncmp("..", findDat2.cFileName, strlen(".."));
        do {
            if (dot1 !=0 && dot2 != 0) {
                if (findDat2.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    SetCurrentDirectory(findDat2.cFileName);                    
                    list2();
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s\n", findDat2.cFileName);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind2, &findDat2));
    }
}

int list(CHAR *startDir) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findDat;
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR cpstartDir[MAX_PATH];
    strcpy_s(cpstartDir, sizeof(cpstartDir), startDir);

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(startDir, &findDat);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE with finding file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        INT dot1 = strncmp(".", findDat.cFileName, strlen("."));
        INT dot2 = strncmp("..", findDat.cFileName, strlen(".."));
        do {
            if (dot1 !=0 && dot2 != 0) {
                if (findDat.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    SetCurrentDirectory(findDat.cFileName);                 
                    list2();
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s\n", findDat.cFileName);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &findDat));
    }
}

int main() {
    list("C:\\*.*");
    return 0;
}
```

This only get files in a current directory

Comment: What's the output when you run it?

Comment: 1) Check the return values of `Get/SetCurrentDirectory`. 2) You change the current directory before the recursive call, but never restore it after the call. 3) The `dot1/2` compares should be done on the whole string, not just the first `1/2` characters, since a valid directory name is allowed to start with dot(s).

Comment: @spartygw it only displays the files on the hard disk (C:\\) i want it to get all files in folder and also subdirectories

Comment: `SetCurrentDirectory` is per process (not thread). It's entirely impossible to implement a robust solution that involves `SetCurrentDirectory`.

Comment: @IInspectable what's the best way to fix this?

Comment: There's only a single rule: Do not ever use relative path names in code. It's that simple, really.

Comment: @IInspectable i changed it from relative path but still not working. I don't know if you can help, i am new in C and windows api

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a recursive function that recurses into each directory found (except for `.` and  `..`).

I don't see the point in using `SetCurrentDirectory`. You don't want to change your working directory, but instead you just want the contents of the lower level path.

So `list` should call itself for each subdirectory with the argument being: the parent path + `\` + the name of the subfolder.

I created a cross platform open source library to traverse an entire tree: https://github.com/brechtsanders/libdirtrav
Maybe this is useful for you so that you wouldn't have to reinvent everything.

Comment: A recursive implementation operating on user-provided data is a guaranteed opportunity for a stack overflow.

Comment: I don't see how you can walk a tree without recursion. But yes, there will always be a maximum limit to how big the tree is before there will be stack/memory issues.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) gets by just fine without a recursive implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable How can you have recursive_directory_iterator without using a recursive implementation? The name itself implies that it uses recursion. And even if it's not implemented using recursive functions it will still require pushing stuff on the stack for each deeper level, so the risk of recursion remains, but only for extremely deeply nested trees.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find any number of implementations if you are interested. Someone who's advertising their own implementation should probably have done that research already, though. The difference between storing temporary state in memory as opposed to encoding it on the stack is, that freestore memory is available in abundant amounts compared to stack memory, that's both very limited and fixed at thread creation time.